# Opening video with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm attmepting to open a video file in OpenCV following the tutorials seen here [OpenCV Python Tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video)

However, upon running the block of code nothing happens. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('768x576.avi')   

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have ffmpeg installed on my system & in my system path.  Additionally I have gstreamer installed on my machine as well.  This file can be opened in windows media player, manipulated in ffmpeg & also opened in VLC.

I'm at a loss here as this should be a straight forward tutorial.

---

Edit 1:  I've installed a bunch of different codecs including the K-Lite Codec Pack and XVid. If I open the file with ffmpeg -i this is what I get

```
C:\sandbox>ffmpeg -i 768x576.avi
ffmpeg version N-64539-gc8b2cf4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  8 2014 22:10:23 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-
libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsox
r --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab -
-enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
--enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-
libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 91.100 / 52. 91.100
  libavcodec     55. 68.102 / 55. 68.102
  libavformat    55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from '768x576.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : MEncoder 2:1.0~rc2-0ubuntu19
  Duration: 00:01:19.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 818 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (div3 / 0x33766964), yuv420p, 768x576, 816 kb/
s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

Edit 2: When I try to do this line by line the following happens

```
C:\sandbox>python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
2.4.9
>>>
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('768x576.avi')
>>> print cap
<VideoCapture 0000000002DC3810>
>>> print cap.get(5)
0.0
>>>
```

Edit 3: The answer wasn't the 100% answer but the comments going down that rabbit hole lead me to this [OpenCV VideoCapture cannot read video in Python but able in VS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374633/opencv-videocapture-cannot-read-video-in-python-but-able-in-vs11)  and THAT is how I figured out my issue

Comment: What happens if you do this line by line in the interpreter? Does `cap` get created with a real memory location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on Windows, and if you are sure that you succeeded opening the file, [most probably you need a codec pack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416623).

Comment: I've downloaded xvideo & also the other xpac that was mentioned.  I can open the file in a myriad of ways including "ffmpeg -i" to get the info.  Open in Windows Media Player & Also open it in a few other video players as well.