# OpenCV - VideoCapture(filename) works in Java but not in Python (Windows 7)

Tags: java, python, opencv

I've been trying to open a video file using OpenCV and process its frames.
I have both avi file and mp4 file, the mp4 file works well in Java but in Python (where I really need it...) it doesn't work (I keep getting None in videocapture.read()).

Any ideas what can this be? how can it be solved?

EDIT: Here's the code I have:

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('myfile.mp4')
video_capture.set(propId=cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, value=1280.0)
video_capture.set(propId=cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, value=720.0)
ret, frame = self.video_capture.read()

if frame is not None:
    # processing code...never reaches here
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374633/opencv-videocapture-cannot-read-video-in-python-but-able-in-vs11) question and the solution provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703998/410487) answer.

Maybe it could help.

Comment: I've done again what it's said in that thread....now I get "warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)"

Comment: Eventually this was solved by your reference + I had a typo in the path. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myfile.mp4')
    ret = cap.set(3,1280)
    ret = cap.set(4,720)
    while True:
       ret,frame = cap.read()
       cv2.imshow('show',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
       break`

Comment: Try again i have edited it. Also let me know what errors you get.

Comment: Actually I get "warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)" since I've copied opencv_ffmpeg249_64.dll to the Python folder

Comment: try giving full path to the video like "c:\path\to\video.mp4"

Comment: I did. It's still doesn't work. Please see my comment in utkrash13's answer as the error I get