# Downloading the first frame of a twitch.tv stream

Tags: python, video-streaming, rtmp

Using [this api](http://livestreamer.tanuki.se/en/latest/api.html) I've managed to download stream data, but I can't figure out how to parse it. I've looked at the RMTP format, but it doesn't seem to match.

```
from livestreamer import Livestreamer

livestreamer = Livestreamer()

# set to a stream that is actually online
plugin = livestreamer.resolve_url("http://twitch.tv/froggen")
streams = plugin.get_streams()
stream = streams['mobile_High']
fd = stream.open()
data = fd.read()
```

I've uploaded an example of the data [here](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1380130622).

Ideally I wouldn't have to parse it as video, I only need the first keyframe as an image. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Ok, I got OpenCV working, it works for grabbing the first frame of a random video file I had. However, it produced a [nonsense image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr2HR.png) when I used the same code on file with stream data.

Comment: I managed to open your file with the OpenCV library (Python code: `capture = cv2.VideoCapture("downloads/( uploadMB.com ) stream.bin")`) I managed to get an image out of it (3 channel, 1280x720), but it looks like a multicolored mess. Are you sure the valid keyframe is in the file?

Comment: I just tried downloading [the first 1 MB of stream data](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1380209204), and using `cv2.VideoCapture`, then `capture.read` but it returns False/None. How did you get an image out of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. Made sure to write as binary data, and OpenCV is able to decode the first video frame. The resulting image had R and B channels switched, but that was easily corrected. Downloading about 300 kB seems to be enough to be sure that the full image is there.

```
import time, Image

import cv2
from livestreamer import Livestreamer

# change to a stream that is actually online
livestreamer = Livestreamer()
plugin = livestreamer.resolve_url("http://twitch.tv/flosd")
streams = plugin.get_streams()
stream = streams['mobile_High']

# download enough data to make sure the first frame is there
fd = stream.open()
data = ''
while len(data) < 3e5:
    data += fd.read()
    time.sleep(0.1)
fd.close()

fname = 'stream.bin'
open(fname, 'wb').write(data)
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(fname)
imgdata = capture.read()[1]
imgdata = imgdata[...,::-1] # BGR -> RGB
img = Image.fromarray(imgdata)
img.save('frame.png')
# img.show()
```

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same task but the call to `capture.read()` returns none. I've tried it with your uploaded bin but I get the same None result. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't call read() on the bin file because ffmpeg (the video decoder) is not properly accessible, so opening the file is failing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows and similar. I fixed by downloading and installing opencv from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/