# Displaying image from video file on UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, video

I have a video file from local server like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/through_your_eyes/file0.mov
```

Before I play that video, I need to show image from video inside tableview. Is there an api to show image from video and when I click, it will play automatically?

My current method is I download video file and I extract image from video file. After that, I show inside my tableview. But I guess it is not quite good.

Comment: The image is a frame of the video?  There's no way to get a frame without the file.  To do this you'll want to make extracting and publishing that frame a server-side part of publishing the video.

Comment: yes it is a frame of the video.

Comment: Never tried it but using OpenCV you might be able to download a portion of the video and extract a frame.  The link is PHP, but something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011691/downloading-the-first-frame-of-a-twitch-tv-stream doubt that AVURLAsset will work with partial files