# OpenCV 2.4.7 with FFMpeg support build with VS 2010 (x86)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm fighting with new version of OpenCV 2.4.7 for almost one week (prev. used 2.4.2). My motivation for the new setup is the fact that I run into problems using the Videowriter for uncompressed grayscale videos (http://answers.opencv.org/question/3603/videowriter-videocapture-and-uncompressed-avi/). In https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1516 "akarsakov" is recommending to build OpenCV without vfw support and open uncompressed video through ffmpeg. That's what I tried to do. I followed basically the instructions mentioned in this video: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

I had successfully build opencv with Qt 5.1.1 (http://answers.opencv.org/question/24184/how-to-compile-opencv-247-with-qt-and-ffmpeg/). But I'm not able to get the VideoWriter & VideoCapture work for me. So what I did:

1. I downloaded the newest ffmpeg build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
2. I generated the vs2010 project disabling VfW and enabling ffmpeg instead:

   ```
   Video I/O:

   Video for Windows:           NO
   DC1394 1.x:                  NO
   DC1394 2.x:                  NO
   FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
     codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
     format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
     util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
     swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
     gentoo-style:              YES
     OpenNI:                    NO
   OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
   PvAPI:                       NO
   GigEVisionSDK:               NO
   DirectShow:                  YES
   Media Foundation:            NO
   XIMEA:                       NO
   ```
3. I added the include directories and libs for ffmpeg to the highgui module.

I was not able to compile OpenCV without any errors but the behaviour what I see is not what I expect:

1. Build OpenCV 2.4.7 without VfW -> VideoWriter.open () returns always false!
2. Build OpenCV 2.4.7 with VfW -> VideoWriter.open () returns true for the time, calling a release() and an open() on the same object returns always a false.
3. With or without ffmpeg -> An VideoCapture.open () gives a error message asking for libiconv-2dll!

Does some had the same problems and is able to point me to my mistake?

Thank you in advance.
cheers

Comment: Not sure of your specifics, but this SO question solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV 2.4.7 requires a more recent version of FFmpeg to work, but that doesn't seem to the issue since you have that covered.

**The cause of your problem could be *[bug](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/versions/17)* #2281**: [VideoCapture::read fails on uncompressed video](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2281).

As an intermediary solution, I suggest you to downgrade to OpenCV 2.4.5.

Comment: Thank you very much for you replay. I guess there is no other way out at this moment.
It's quite annoying, cause due to this bug which was merged with pull request 1516 (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1516) I did the update :-S.
thank anyhow. cheers