# Playing a video with python cv2

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I'm trying to play an `avi` file with python cv2

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture('lot1.avi')
```

but the `cap.isOpen()` is always `False`.
Dose it have to do with the file type? do I have to install somthing?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding **opencv_ffmpeg.dll** to the `c:/python27/` folder and changing it's name to **opencv_ffmpeg246**. 
I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672734/2154827

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
cv.CaptureFromFile()
```

There is some code you can look at here if you run in to any more problems: [Watch Video in Python with OpenCV](http://web.michaelchughes.com/how-to/watch-video-in-python-with-opencv). Hope this helps you!

Comment: Is the avi coded with a codec? Try to find out and post back ;)