# I can't call the video that is stored in my laptop with VideoCapture() function of opencv

Tags: python, opencv

It still gives the error. When I write the below code:

If I write: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, my code works properly. but whenever I write `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Users\Anjali\Documents\Python_Files\Video_tracking\slow.mp4')`, it does't work.

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Users\Anjali\Documents\Python_Files\Video_tracking\slow.mp4')

while (True):

ret, frame = cap.read()

#gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It gives the following error, please help me in this:

```
cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Comment: try using 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\Anjali\\Documents\\Python_Files\\Video_tracking\slow.mp4')

Comment: Refer to similar question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: "\" is an escape character in Windows.


It's always a good idea to check the value of `ret`. It'll tell you if the capture worked or not. Another member of `VideoCapture` is the function `isOpened()`.