# python.exe crashing when running basic OpenCV example

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm just following the second example from this [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html) and using a different video. Can anyone help solve the problem of why it crashes? I thought it would be my cheap Windows 7 running on 2 GB RAM, but it's not even using up the RAM when it crashes.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\\OpenCV\\Cam1_Indoor.avi")

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1:** 
I still can't get this working, but I have tried to debug it some more. I found that regardless of the video file name I give it (even if it's totally bogus), the same crash happens.

**UPDATE 2:** 
I found that the code below works on images, so my problem may have to do with video capture.

```
im_in = cv2.imread("F:\\OpenCV\\nickel.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fgmask = fgbg.apply(im_in)
cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: try checking if the frame is empty before doing your processing. In C++ it's `if(frame.empty()){
            std::cerr<<"frame is empty"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }`

Comment: Does it crash when you use the same video as the tutorial?

Comment: @PaulRooney - I don't know where to get the video they use, hence I am using my own video

Comment: @GPPK - I tried `frame.empty()` but got the error `object has no attribute 'empty'`

Comment: Turns out this was the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Add this below import statements

```
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
```