# How to read in a video file with cv2.VideoCapture?

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and simply trying to read in a video file and display it. Unfortunately, it looks like I can't even open the video. Any ideas on what may be preventing me from opening a video file? I can open images just fine. Can anyone help me out? Thanks so much.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\\OpenCV\\Cam1_Indoor.avi")

if cap.isOpened():
    print "Opened"
else:
    print "Not opened"

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

> Not opened
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        11 while(1):
>        12     ret, frame = cap.read()
>   ---> 13     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
>        14     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
>        15         break
>
> error:
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:271:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: It looks like you're trying to display an image with no size, possibly because `ret, frame = cap.read()` failed.

Comment: @101 - it looks like I can't even open the file, according to `isOpened`. Any ideas on what may be preventing me from opening a video file? I can open images just fine.

Comment: Maybe this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows

Comment: @101 - oh my, yes that solved it. Thanks so much!!!