# Python, Tkinter not making a window

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a app that detects outside video input and automatically switches shows it, I made a system where it would make a tkinter window and show the webcam footage in it, But a Tkinter window wont show up.

I woul've used cv2.imshow but i don't want to use that for the time it takes to make the frame.

```
import cv2
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack()

print("[INFO] Making variables")
ImageSource = 0
window_name = "AutoCam"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource)
print("[INFO] Made variables ")


def CheckSource():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource)
    while cap.isOpened():
        _, frame = cap.read()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            break

        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, CheckSource)

        print("[INFO] cv2.imshow done")

    else:
        print("[INFO] Looking for image source.")
        CheckSource()


CheckSource()
root.mainloop()
```

Any and all help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What did you not understand from my comments to your [previous same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031039/opencv-and-tkinter-how-can-i-automatically-show-webcam-video)?

Comment: Not really. I just did something i've no idea about, how would i execute this

Comment: As i wrote, your `while ...` is **blocking**, remove it.

Comment: But how do i then check if my webcamera is opened?

Comment: Would a if statement also block it?

Comment: No, do  `if cap.isOpened(): ... else: # delay using .after(10 * 100,`. Keep in mind using `.after(...` calling yourself is your `while loop`. Therefore you need a `break` condition also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199808/discussion-between-gottaaimhigherpal-and-stovfl).