# Can't open video with OpenCV 2.4.11 in Conda

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I just installed OpenCV on my Anaconda, and I tested it with the following code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('MyMovie.avi')
print(cap.isOpened())
```

The result always show `false`, but capturing cam and picture works well.
My OpenCV version is 2.4.11 could anyone help out with this?

Comment: Try adding opencv_ffmpegXXX as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows)

Comment: @Miki Thank you for the suggestion. I add the path to Windows PATH environment variable. modified opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll into opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll. However, it still doesn't work.