# Sequence of images to video in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a series of images in *.tif format that I want to use to create a video.  I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 in Python 2.7.  Below is a snippet of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

nIMAGES = 10
files = glob.glob(DIR + '\\' + tpname +'\\*.tif' )
image_stack = np.empty((500, 220, nIMAGES))
mov = DIR + '\\' + tpname + '\\' + tpname + '_mov.avi'
MOV = cv2.VideoWriter(filename=mov, fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F', 'M', 'P', '4'), fps=2, frameSize=(220, 500)) # frame size is 220 x 500

for i in np.arange(0, nIMAGES):
    print 'Working on: ' + files[i][-14:-4]
    image = cv2.imread(files[i], 0)
    crop_image = image[50:550, 252:472] #crop y:h, x:w

 # now let's create the movie:
    crop_image = cv2.applyColorMap(crop_image, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    MOV.write(crop_image)

MOV.release()
```

When I run this code, I create an AVI file that is 0 Kb (it hasn't saved anything to it).

I believe I am missing something like `frame = cv2.VideoCapture.read(crop_image)` in which case I would convert the write line to `MOV.write(frame)`.  However, I get an `AttributeError` in that the `VideoCapture.read` is not an attribute.

I am using this OpenCV webpage as my guide: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: does it print all the "working on ..." files? In C++ API you would have to add the opencv_ffmpeg.dll to successfully write frames.

Comment: Yes.  It does print the `Working on:` message. It does read the images in and it does crop them appropriately.  I can display these images with `cv2.imshow`

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows . Same should be the case for VideoWriter, so add the opencv_ffmpeg dll to a location where your program can find it!

Comment: wasn't the file already created in your old version? `When I run this code, I create an AVI file that is 0 Kb` ? I'm quite sure that the right dll file isn't found yet...

Comment: OR: the codec isn't supported by your ffmpeg dll. See http://answers.opencv.org/question/12959/videowriter-fourcc-1-works-but-cv_fourcccram-does-not/ and try a different codec. For example start with the 'MJPG' codec. If that works you can try different codecs.

Comment: Ok.  So it now creates a video.  But it only has the first image of the sequence.  To recap: I copied all the contents of `ffmpeg` to `C:\Anaconda\ ` (since I am using Spyder and Anaconda).  I changed the names of the `.dll` files to: `opencv_ffmpeg310.dll` and `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll`.  It now creates a video file `*.avi` that is 100 kb (the size of one image).

Comment: is the size of all your images `(220, 500)`? If not you'll have to resize them programmatically (cv2.resize), they must fit the Recorder settings. In addition check that color/grayscale is set correctly and fitting to your images, or convert the images programmatically.

Comment: I got it to work!  @Micka you are the man!  I need to change the codec to `fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')`.  It now works beautifully.

Comment: nice to hear that. But be aware that MJPEG isn't a great video codec, so if you get problems in video quality and video size you might want to find different codecs.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make two changes to get this to work:

1. Following the advice on this question: [OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows) I had to copy the  `fmpeg.dll` files to my Python directory (`C:\Anaconda`).  I also had to relabel the folders to include the version of my opencv (3.1.0) e.g. `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll`
2. The other change I needed to make was to change my codec to MJPG

Much appreciation goes to @Micka for helping me very quickly.