# Video file not opening?(opencv 3.1.0 windows)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, opencv3.0

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("StopMoti2001.mpeg")
if cap.isOpened():
    print 'fine'
else:
    print 'not fine'
```

output is 'not fine' I have checked for various videos and I also moved the ffmpeg file moving to PATH and still the problem remains same. can you please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, Actually I was working in anaconda, so instead of moving ffmpeg to Python27, I should move it to Anaconda dll folder to make it work.

Comment: Would you elaborate on what you mean by 'moving ffmpeg to Python27'? Did you move the videofile to the python installation directory?

Comment: I mean [this..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11703998/3636782) so instead of moving into C://Python27/ move to C:\Users\$username\Anaconda2\DLLs folder

Comment: So your problem was the OpenCV library not being in the right folder, not FFMPEG

Comment: No, the `opencv_ffmpeg310.dll` file only