# Opencv3.0.0 VideoCapture not working on Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ffmpeg

cv2.Videocapture() works fine while using the camera，but while reading the local video, there is a WARNING: Couldn't read movie file

Here is my test code:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test2.avi')
print cap.isOpened()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error occurred:

```html
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file test2.avi
False
```

I found that on Windows, there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows) about it.I copied all the files in /Users/xxx/opencv/3rdparty/ffmpeg to my python path, and renamed  'opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll' to 'opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll',  but it still didn't work.

Besides, I found that I couldn't open test2.avi by QuickTime Player.  Is that a possible factor that caused the error?

Comment: If you can't open a file manually from your video player then I think it's broken. Try a file that you can open in video player and try to use videocapture on it

Comment: Thanks. It works when I use another video file. And I still have a question，why 2 same format video like 'mp4', one can't be opened, but the other can?:)

Comment: I suppose one of them is broken or there is some encoding issue.

Comment: Install ffmpeg command tool utils and run "ffmpeg -i badvideo.mp4". Than post results to your question